# Strange behaviour with floats and string conversion

Tags: python, floating-point, python-2.x

I've typed this into python shell:

```
>>> 0.1*0.1
0.010000000000000002
```

I expected that 0.1*0.1 is not 0.01, because I know that 0.1 in base 10 is periodic in base 2.

```
>>> len(str(0.1*0.1))
4
```

I expected to get 20 as I've seen 20 characters above. Why do I get 4?

```
>>> str(0.1*0.1)
'0.01'
```

Ok, this explains why I `len` gives me 4, but why does `str` return `'0.01'`?

```
>>> repr(0.1*0.1)
'0.010000000000000002'
```

Why does `str` round but `repr` not? (I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/562769), but I would like to know how they have decided when `str` rounds a float and when it doesn't)

```
>>> str(0.01) == str(0.0100000000001)
False
>>> str(0.01) == str(0.01000000000001)
True
```

So it seems to be a problem with the accuracy of floats. I thought Python would use IEEE 754 single precicion floats. So I've checked it like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h> // printf

union myUnion {
    uint32_t i; // unsigned integer 32-bit type (on every machine)
    float f;    // a type you want to play with
};

int main() {
    union myUnion testVar;
    testVar.f = 0.01000000000001f;
    printf("%f\n", testVar.f);

    testVar.f = 0.01000000000000002f;
    printf("%f\n", testVar.f);

    testVar.f = 0.01f*0.01f;
    printf("%f\n", testVar.f);
}
```

I got:

```
0.010000
0.010000
0.000100
```

Python gives me:

```
>>> 0.01000000000001
0.010000000000009999
>>> 0.01000000000000002
0.010000000000000019
>>> 0.01*0.01
0.0001
```

Why does Python give me these results?

(I use Python 2.6.5. If you know of differences in the Python versions, I would also be interested in them.)

Comment: not sure why the users deleted their answers, but indeed the behaviour is explained in [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: `float('4.1') * 100 == 409.99999999999994`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The crucial requirement on `repr` is that it should round-trip; that is, `eval(repr(f)) == f` should give `True` in all cases.

In Python 2.x (before 2.7) `repr` works by doing a `printf` with format `%.17g` and discarding trailing zeroes.  This is guaranteed correct (for 64-bit floats) by IEEE-754.  Since 2.7 and 3.1, Python uses a more intelligent algorithm that can find shorter representations in some cases where `%.17g` gives unnecessary non-zero terminal digits or terminal nines.  See [What's new in 3.1?](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes) and [issue 1580](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580).

Even under Python 2.7, `repr(0.1 * 0.1)` gives `"0.010000000000000002"`. This is because `0.1 * 0.1 == 0.01` is `False` under IEEE-754 parsing and arithmetic; that is, the nearest 64-bit floating-point value to `0.1`, when multiplied by itself, yields a 64-bit floating-point value that is not the nearest 64-bit floating-point value to `0.01`:

```
>>> 0.1.hex()
'0x1.999999999999ap-4'
>>> (0.1 * 0.1).hex()
'0x1.47ae147ae147cp-7'
>>> 0.01.hex()
'0x1.47ae147ae147bp-7'
                 ^ 1 ulp difference
```

The difference between `repr` and `str` (pre-2.7/3.1) is that `str` formats with 12 decimal places as opposed to 17, which is non-round-trippable but produces more readable results in many cases.

Comment: +1.  And in Python >= 3.2, the difference between `repr` and `str` for floats is gone entirely. (And about time, too :-)

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm your behaviour

```
ActivePython 2.6.4.10 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jan 22 2010, 17:24:21) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> repr(0.1)
'0.10000000000000001'
>>> repr(0.01)
'0.01'
```

Now, the docs [claim](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes) that in Python <2.7

> the value of `repr(1.1)` was computed as `format(1.1, '.17g')`

This is a slight simplification.

---

Note that this is all to do with the string *formatting* code -- in memory, all Python floats are just stored as C++ doubles, so there is never going to be a difference between them.

Also, it's kind of unpleasant to work with the full-length string for a float even if you know that there's a better one. Indeed, in modern Pythons a new algorithm is used for float formatting, that picks the shortest representation in a smart way.

---

I spent a while looking this up in the source code, so I'll include the details here in case you're interested. You can skip this section.

In `floatobject.c`, we see

```
static PyObject *
float_repr(PyFloatObject *v)
{
    char buf[100];
    format_float(buf, sizeof(buf), v, PREC_REPR);

    return PyString_FromString(buf);
}
```

which leads us to look at `format_float`. Omitting the NaN/inf special cases, it is:

```
format_float(char *buf, size_t buflen, PyFloatObject *v, int precision)
{
    register char *cp;
    char format[32];
    int i;

    /* Subroutine for float_repr and float_print.
       We want float numbers to be recognizable as such,
       i.e., they should contain a decimal point or an exponent.
       However, %g may print the number as an integer;
       in such cases, we append ".0" to the string. */

    assert(PyFloat_Check(v));
    PyOS_snprintf(format, 32, "%%.%ig", precision);
    PyOS_ascii_formatd(buf, buflen, format, v->ob_fval);
    cp = buf;
    if (*cp == '-')
        cp++;
    for (; *cp != '\0'; cp++) {
        /* Any non-digit means it's not an integer;
           this takes care of NAN and INF as well. */
        if (!isdigit(Py_CHARMASK(*cp)))
            break;
    }
    if (*cp == '\0') {
        *cp++ = '.';
        *cp++ = '0';
        *cp++ = '\0';
        return;
    }

    <some NaN/inf stuff>
}
```

We can see that

So this first initialises some variables and checks that `v` is a well-formed float. It then prepares a format string:

```
PyOS_snprintf(format, 32, "%%.%ig", precision);
```

Now PREC_REPR is defined elsewhere in `floatobject.c` as 17, so this computes to `"%.17g"`. Now we call

```
PyOS_ascii_formatd(buf, buflen, format, v->ob_fval);
```

With the end of the tunnel in sight, we look up [`PyOS_ascii_formatd`](http://www6.uniovi.es/python/dev/src/c/html/pystrtod_8c.html#a4) and discover that it uses `snprintf` internally.

Comment: I agree that the claim in the What's New doc for Python is a simplification of the old behavior.  Perhaps a better description can be found in the [enhancement request](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580) that lead to the change: "The current float repr() always calculates the 17 first digits of the
decimal representation of a float, and displays all of them (discarding
trailing zeros)."

Comment: Here's the link for [2.6.5 `PyOS_ascii_formatd`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/99af4b44e7e4/Python/pystrtod.c#l375) and [`ensure_minimum_exponent_length`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/99af4b44e7e4/Python/pystrtod.c#l223), though I don't know which platforms require the latter to conform with C99.

Answer (score 1):

[from python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> In versions prior to Python 2.7 and Python 3.1, Python rounded this value to 17 significant digits, giving `‘0.10000000000000001’`. In current versions, Python displays a value based on the shortest decimal fraction that rounds correctly back to the true binary value, resulting simply in `‘0.1’`.