# python complex number print result different from shell output

Tags: python, math, complex-numbers

```
>>> a=4.
>>> b=3.
r = sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2)
x = atan(b/a)
a = r * cos(x)
b = r * sin(x)
k = 0
y = (2 * pi * k + x) /3

root1 = r ** (1./3) * ( cos(y)+ 1j * sin(y) )
root11 = root1**4/root1
>>> root11
(3.999999999999999+2.999999999999999j)
>>> print root11
(4+3j)
```

How do I print out this complex number in this '(3.999999999999999+2.999999999999999j)' form? I tried

```
>>> print '%15f %15fi' % (root11.real, root11.imag)
4.000000        3.000000i
```

please help

Comment: shell prints the `repr` output of a decimal number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour with floats and string conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345334/strange-behaviour-with-floats-and-string-conversion)

Comment: because `print` (actually `float.__str__`) and `%15f` are rounding the number

Comment: Python 3 seems to print `(3.999999999999999+2.999999999999999j)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments suggest `print root11.__repr__()` works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the new format syntax,

```
print "{0:.15f}+{1:.15f}i".format(root11.real, root11.imag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
print '%.15f %.15fi' % (root11.real, root11.imag)
```

Notice there is a `.` before the `15f` to format the precision after the decimal. If you do not have the `.`, you are specifying the field width.

In my machine (Python 2.7.3), The result is:

```
3.999999999999999 2.999999999999999i
```