# Floats print differently when shown in dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary, numbers, key

I'm creating a dictionary with this simple code:

```
pixel_histogram = {}
min_value = -0.2
max_value = 0.2
interval_size = (math.fabs(min_value) + math.fabs(max_value))/bins

for i in range(bins):
    key = min_value+(i*interval_size)
    print key
    pixel_histogram[key] = 0
    print pixel_histogram
```

But I'm a little surprised 'cause I got these values with my prints:

```
#Printing keys
-0.2
-0.16
-0.12
-0.08
-0.04
0.0
0.04
0.08
0.12
0.16

#Printing the dictionary
{0.0: 0, 
-0.08000000000000002: 0, 
0.15999999999999998: 0, 
-0.16: 0, 
0.12: 0, 
-0.12000000000000001: 0, 
0.08000000000000002: 0, 
-0.04000000000000001: 0, 
-0.2: 0, 
0.03999999999999998: 0}
```

I didn't figure out why the values are different and how could I solve this.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: If you need to use exact floating-point numbers, try using the Decimal class: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html.

Comment: While that explains the output of the second case, it doesn't explain why the first output differs from the second.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345334/strange-behaviour-with-floats-and-string-conversion

Comment: Sorry for the noob question. Didn't know about the difference between `str` and `repr`(didn't even know this). Trying to learn more about Python. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python's `print` statement uses `str()` on the item being printed.  For floating-point values, `str()` will print up to certain number of decimal values.

When printing a dictionary, the `print` statement is calling `str()` on the dictionary object.  The dictionary, in its `__str__()` method definition, uses `repr()` on the keys.  The `repr()` function for floating-point values prints to more decimal places than the `str()` function does.

The reason dictionaries use `repr()` and not `str()` for keys is that you almost definitely want to see `print {'1': 1}` print differently than `print {1: 1}`.

Comment: Thank you @Alok--. This is just what I would like to know. Sorry for the noob question, I didn't know this about the `print` method in Python.

Comment: @pceccon No problem.  As an aside, it's not really a good idea to store floating-point values as keys in dictionaries, since that implies that you want to be able to do exact comparison on the keys.  (If you know that the values you're going to use as keys in that dictionary can be represented exactly with floating-point values, then it should be OK.)

Answer (score -3):

The values are the same. In the first case, they have been truncated or rounded to decimal places. Surely you are familiar with the rounding of numbers?

Comment: -1: This is an unhelpful answer. It doesn't explain the root of the problem.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Yes it does. The root of the problem is that the numbers are being rounded.

Comment: @delnan Looks like the print statement to me.