# Python: Returning Floats Incorrectly

Tags: python-2.7

I have a Python function as follows:

```py
def point_double((xp,yp)):
    s = (3.0 * pow(xp,2) - 1)/(2.0*yp) # s = 2.6
    xr = pow(s,2) - (2 * xp) # xr = 0.76
    yr = s * (xp - xr) - yp # yr = 0.824

    return (xr,yr)
```

When I call `point_double((3,5))` I get a return value of `(0.7600000000000007, 0.8239999999999981)` rather than the correct value of `(0.76,0.824)`

Adding `print xr, yr` just before the return line prints the desired result, but changing that to `print (xr,yr)` prints the incorrect value

Can someone explain to me why this happens, and also help me overcome this so that the function returns the desired value

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: using xp*xp, or xp**2 instead of floating point pow could help too.

Comment: The floating point error part makes sense but can anyone explain why `print xr` returns `0.76` and but the return statement gives `xr = 0.7600000000000007`

Comment: it's not the return, its the prints (i.e. your code is "ok"). You can see that in my answer below: basically, if you call it, then print the xr and yr's explicitly they will be shortened, whereas if you print the *tuple* they will be longer.

Comment: It's because `str(xr)` and `repr(xr)` behave differently - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13346122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, its two things - firstly its that computers can't represent some numbers very well (like 1/3rd), and secondly its how "print" is manipulating your code:

So:

```
xr, yr = point_double((3,5))

print xr
print yr

print (xr,yr)
```

that will produce:

```
0.76
0.824
(0.7600000000000007, 0.8239999999999981)
```

You should consider instead printing a bit like this:

```
print (" x: %s y: %s" % (xr, yr))
```

I'm struggling to find the exact reference in print as to how it calls `str()` on the print, because in 2.7 its an inbuilt. Effectively by using % or string.format, you are enforcing and controlling how the float is being rendered.

[zero-piraeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014938/zero-piraeus) noted:

> When you print an object, its **str**() method is called. The
>   **str**() method for a tuple (or any other inbuilt collection) calls **repr**() for each item in the collection.

Note that the *actual value* of xr is the longer, inaccurate one.

Edit: This is a good guide (for python 3) about how floating points are stored and other ways of printing them https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: When you print an object, its `__str__()` method is called. The `__str__()` method for a tuple (or any other inbuilt collection) calls `__repr__()` for each item in the collection.

Comment: Thanks @Jmons, that's really helpful. Frustrating, but helpful!